# undefine a variable in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, variables, undefined

In order to save some time typing same phrase many times, I defined some variables in in BASH (not a bash file, just the command line bash). How careless I was to give a variable wrong name `foo1` instead of `foo`. So, I want to undefine `foo1`.

I know I can set `foo1` empty and define `foo`. By doing this, `foo1` is still there and may confuse. I cannot use `unset` to undefine `foo1` because it is not an environment variable.

**Question**: How to undefine a variable in BASH?

Comment: It doesn't matter that `foo1` isn't an environment variable, you can still use `unset` to unset it. Also not sure what you mean by `foo1 is still there`?

Comment: @BroSlow Thank you. I mistyped `unset $foo1`. I am such a careless beginner. shame

Comment: Technically, there is no such thing as an environment variable. All variables are shell variables, some of which may be marked for export to child processes. "Environment" variables are just shell variables that were created at startup based on strings found in the environment.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You just need to use the command `unset`:

```
unset foo1
```

It doesn't matter if `foo1` isn't an environment variable.

Comment: Why was this voted down? I would add `help unset` info, but it's obviously a good answer.

Comment: I think it's because of your comment but it were posted in the same time, sorry.

Comment: No problem. Think we were typing at same time. Happens all the time on SO, and definitely not a reason to vote a correct answer down. Though looks like the person removed it.

Answer (score 2):

as @BroSlow comments, yes you will use `unset`:

```
$ foo1=something
$ foo="something else"
$ set | grep ^foo
foo='something else'
foo1=something
$ unset foo1
$ set | grep ^foo
foo='something else'
```

Comment: I think the question may not be clearly worded but OP is asking for a way to avoid `bash`'s evaluating-undefined-variables-as-empty feature.

Comment: Really? Despite the OP twice typing "How to undefine a variable"?

Comment: Poorly worded, like I said.  "How careless I was to give a variable wrong name foo1 instead of foo. So, I want to undefine foo1."  What utility would there be to this unless OP wants to save themselves from the time lost debugging a problem where `echo ${foo1}` doesn't halt execution, just chugs merrily along?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set -u` in order to "Attempt to use undefined variable outputs error message, and forces an exit".

Or add `-u` to the shebang line like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash -u
```